# How to use `\monthiname`, `\monthiiname`, ... commands from `babel`?

Tags: babel, date

Within the `babel` package, for each language, the month names are already defined as `\month<roman number>name` commands.

I was looking then for a solution that would provide me with the month name in the proper language using only `babel` and tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian, english, french]{babel}

\newcommand{\monthnametoday}[1][\languagename]{{\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{#1}\csname month\romannumeral\month name\endcsname\space -- \today\relax\par}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\monthnametoday (expected: ``septembre'')\\
\monthnametoday[italian] (expected: ``settembre'')\\
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\monthnametoday (expected: ``september'')
\end{otherlanguage}}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not what I would expect :/ I obtain:

[image: compilation result]

As you can see, the `\today` command gets properly translated in the selected language. But the `\monthXXname` macros are stuck in the main language :/

Any way I could use them for that purpose? How? I've looked at the documentation of `babel` and its code, and did not find any hint.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a neat way, using only `babel`, but instead of using the default `.ldf` files, it uses the `.ini` files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel} % do not load languages here
\babelprovide[import]{french} % load french .ini file
\babelprovide[import]{english} % load english .ini file
\babelprovide[import, main]{italian} % load italian .ini file, and make it the main language

\newcommand{\monthnametoday}[1][\languagename]{{\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{#1}\csname month\romannumeral\month name\endcsname\space -- \today\relax\par}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\monthnametoday (expected: ``settembre'')\\
\monthnametoday[french] (expected: ``septembre'')\\
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\monthnametoday (expected: ``september'')
\end{otherlanguage}}
\end{document}
```

Very simple and working perfectly :)

[image]

Comment: You can use **both** methods at the same time. That way you won't lost the additional features provided by the `ldf` files.

Comment: In other words, `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` `\babelprovide[import]{italian}`is legitimate.

Comment: oh cool. I did not test all the features babel provide, so good to know you can combine both.

Answer (score 4):

french is the only language that already uses this new interface. You must add the definitions for the other languages yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian, english, french]{babel}
\StartBabelCommands*{italian}{date}
  \SetStringLoop{month#1name}{%
      gennaio,febbraio,marzo,aprile,maggio,giugno,%
    luglio,agosto,settembre,ottobre,novembre,%
    dicembre}
 \EndBabelCommands     

\StartBabelCommands*{english}{date}
  \SetStringLoop{month#1name}{%
    January,February,March,April,May,June,%
      July,August,September,October,November,%
      December}
 \EndBabelCommands


\newcommand{\monthnametoday}[1][\languagename]{{\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{#1}\csname month\romannumeral\month name\endcsname\space -- \today\relax\par}}

\begin{document}


\noindent\monthnametoday (expected: ``septembre'')\\
\monthnametoday[italian] (expected: ``settembre'')\\
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\monthnametoday (expected: ``september'')
\end{otherlanguage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh my it is indeed only defined for French :/ too bad. Thanks for your answer. That means `babel` cannot be used as an out-of-the-box solution for mutli-language month names :/

Comment: a question remains though: why `babel` is not constructing its `today` command based on localized month names as for French: that would allow to build flexible custom multi-language dates. Instead each local `today` is "hard coded" :/

Comment: Another thing. `babel` relies on `.ini` files for each languages. From what I see, they all define proper month / day names (long and short versions). There must be a way to use that existing information...

Comment: One of the goals of the `ini` files is to provide the ‘new style’ dates and captions  for languages not definining them. See my comment above.